# Getting NSTimeZone from CLLocationCoordinates2D

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimezone

I want to current time of `CLLocationCoordinate2D`.

For example I am in a city in east coast and should know what the time at a remote location in California. I have CLLocationCoordinate2D. Neither `CLLocation` nor `CLPlacemark` give me `NSLocale` or `NSTimeZone`. Is there a way to do this without using 3rd party services?

Comment: Sure, find/create a small database with latitude/longitude boundaries and their timezone offsets or names, then compare your lat/long with the entries to get the desired result. Googling should provide you with some .txt file lists that you can use to create your own; sorry I can't provide any but have done it before this way.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this GitHub project: https://github.com/Alterplay/APTimeZones.

It help with NSTimeZone's and CLLocation.

Comment: Is there any other alternative? The APTimeZones library does not seem to support daylight saving times in some cases